# ssis package won't load all rows when run automatically in sql agent but loads all rows when run manually in sql agent

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

i am experiencing something very weired. and would like to get some help.

I have a SSIS package which is deployed on server and a sql job is created in SQL agent.

When i run the job in SQL agent manually by selecting : 
SQL Server Agent:- JObs:- Package1:- Start JOb...

It workd fine. It results all the number of rows from source to destinaltion for a selected time frame.

Now This job is scheduled to run automatically 4 times a day(each 6 hours intervals). When this job runs automatically it skips some rows each time its run but only for few tables.

I really have no idea. that why the same job results different number of rows when run manually and automatcially.

Answers would be highy appreciated.

Thanks
jagz

Comment: If the rows to be moved are selected by a query, posting that query might be helpful.

Comment: How do you know it skips the rows? How do you know it's the automated invocation of the job and not simply a byproduct of you not running the job manually every 6 hours

Comment: I will provide details. I want an automated job which runs every 6 hours and load data from vendor sql database to our sql database. So I am doing incremental load in my ssis package. My package consist of a execute SQL task - which runs a query : SELECT MAX( [TimeStamp]) as last_Loaddt  FROM tblDailySum. Now this statement find the last record upto which data is loaded. Now I store this in a single result set in a variable .

Comment: Then i use  a dataflow task which runs following query from source database:
 SELECT * FROM   dbo.tbldailysum WHERE [timestamp] >= ?     
   and ? is passed from the variable which recieve value fromexecute SQL task.       10 diff tables have the same scanerio. Now i have a job created for this SSIS package. 
I do a count check : DECLARE
start_time as datetime = '2015-01-01',
end_time as datetime='2015-02-02'
BEGIN
select 'tblDailySum' as Table_Name, count(*) as No_Of_Rows  
,MAX([timestamp]) from tblDailySum where [TimeStamp] >= start_time and [TimeStamp] <= end_time
END

Comment: So this health check script is run at source and destination database to check if all the rows are inserted correctly. 
Now when the job is run automatically it skips some number of rows every 6 hours but from few tables.
 NOn the other hand when i run this job manually and do health check by count script it shows me accurate results 
 (same number of rows between those time periods).

Comment: Maybe worth to doublecheck. How many job steps do you have? Does the job start at step 1?

Comment: It has one step. but the thing to consider is i am running job itself-- manually or automatically.. which actually delivers diff results. so the job gives diff results when run automatically

Comment: Please help someone ??